# Why is java.sql.Statement an interface and not an abstract class?

Tags: java, jdbc

Why is `java.sql.Statement` an interface and not an abstract class? Some arrogant interviewer rejected a candidate because he didn't know.

Comment: That "arrogant" interviewer also googled on the web and found the question online and the answer (which he/she didn't know at first). Just guessing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because author decided that there was no need to make any implementation of methods.

Answer (score 10):

Because there's *nothing* which can be provided as default implementation which will work with **any** database engine the world is aware of.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say. They could make it a dummy `abstract class` that would do pretty much nothing. By doing that it would make the all real implementations unable to extend any other class. An `interface` on the other hand is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much Statement is a skeleton class (interface) so that database driver developers knows what they need to implement when they `implements` Statement.

As part of the [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/overview.html) `Statement` couldn't be abstract as there wasn't any way they could have have "default" implementations that could range **all** databases.

Comment: A bit pedantic but I wouldn't describe an Interface as a "Skeleton class". Surely an Abstract class is more like a skeleton class?

Comment: @Jim, for lack of better word, I used skeleton seeing it has no life, but has a structure (interfaces has abstract methods but no implementations). Abstract classes has a bit of flesh (implementations) so not only does it has structure, but bit of meaning. Interfaces says, this is what I have but I am pretty useless as is on my own....I hope you understood what I just wrote.